# Restricting wordpress login sessions for a web app

Tags: users, login, session

I am creating a webgl unity app that sits on a wp site and uses the wp accounts to store data. It works really well, however an issue I have is that currently a user can be logged in on two machines at once, and therefore use the app with the same account on two machines concurrently. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening? I have tried a few plugins that prevent simultaneous logins, however all of them assume that the user will be refreshing/changing page often, and so do not work for an app where you will stay on the same page for the whole session.

As I type this I've realised a potential workaround is setting some sort of flag in the database when the app starts and checking for it on login/clearing it when the game ends, but that sounds a bit janky and I am not sure how reliable onapplicationquit is in webgl, so would prefer a wp based solution rather than unity. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are things that you can do but nothing can truly do this in a foolproof way, HTTP is a stateless protocol, even duplicating the tab could circumvent this. Lots of mitigations will cause issues, e.g. IP based mitigations would cripple mobile users and people using 4G/3G internet ( common for rural users with fixeed modems and larger 4G antenna )

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Yeah highly doubtful there's anything perfect, but would be happy with something fuzzy that would at the very least dissuade people from doing it. But yeah as you say, cant do anything that's going to effect user experience too severely.

Comment: This might be a simple solution.  While not perfect, should cover many of the situations you are trying to prevent.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43356851/1688002